# What are use-cases for Docker App and Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to provide to customer

1. My ASP.NET Core Web Service
2. PostgreSQL + my Demo database
3. Redis Server

Now I can provide 3 Docker images and user can run them separately and try to work.

But for the user it is complicated. IS it possible to provide single Docker containing all 3 dockers inside?

What to use: Docker-compose or Docker App? What difference ?

Comment: You would almost always run your application, database, and cache in three separate containers.  Compose would be a very typical way to orchestrate them.

Comment: Why not Docker App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use docker-compose, because Docker App also use it. Docker App eases publishing your app, but still is based on docker-compose. Docker App is in experimental faze.